# I don't understand the correct operation of substring in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulty performing a substring to a field in my dataframe, I cannot correctly extract the values I need, I have reviewed the documentation but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. I leave an example:

```
>> df['date']
20200131
```

I am trying to substring to get '2020' + '01' + '31' independently to apply a format as follows:

```
>>df_t = df_test['date'].astype(str).str[:4]  #Work OK
  2020
>>df_t = df_test['date'].astype(str).str[5:2]  #No work
  
  df_t = df_test['date'].astype(str).str[7:2]  #No work
```

I have also tried another method, but with the same result:

```
df_t = df_test['date'].astype(str).str.slice(5,2) #No work
```

What am I doing wrong?

From already thank you very much!!

I will listen to your answers,

Regards!

Comment: do you actually just want the year of the date?

Comment: slices in python are `[start:end+1]`, so your second example should be: `...str[5:7]`. But if you actually want the components of the date, there are much better ways to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I already managed to understand how it works. Regards!

Comment: instead of parsing strings, you should be doing e.g., `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df_t = df_test['date'].astype(str).str[5:6]

df_t = df_test['date'].astype(str).str[7:8]

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand how it worked;)

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in `[begin:end:step]`
begin is included, and end is excluded

As when you ask for `[5,2]` you ask for the part starting at the index 5 and ending at the index 2 with the default step of 1, that is empty.

You can get the right thing with `[:4]` then `[4:6]` and `[6:]`